# How to run Private Ethereum Node forever

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs

I want to run my **Private Ethereum Node continuously**, even if it stops in between,it should get started automatically. Like **forever npm in node** which ensures that a given script runs continuously. so is there any tool which can be used to monitor the Ethereum node, and should start the node automatically if it stops.

Comment: You can use `screen` for this. To run the process in bg. But to keep in restarting you need a script (probably in bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run a watchdog daemon that keeps geth alive. I use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to keep my Geth processes running if they crash or get stopped.